# Bibliography using biblatex, XeTeX and bidi creating wrong punctuation

Tags: biblatex, xetex, punctuation, endnotes

Although a Newbie, I have been using XeTeX, `bidi` and `biblatex` with great success in Urdu. I have alphabetical footnotes with most of the secondary sources in the endnotes. The endnotes and bibliography are in English, whereas the rest is in Urdu.

However,the bibliography has a punctuation problem. Periods and parentheses are not where they should be (see example). I have the feeling it has to do with the LRE command. It's nearly as if the text is LRE in the bibliography whereas the punctuation is still trying to work RLE. I have tried all forms of `bidi` commands, that hasn't helped.

Any ideas?

My minimal example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\TeXXeTstate=1

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir} 
\usepackage[a5paper, left=.915in,right=.915in,top=1.651cm,bottom=1.524cm]   {geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}% font selecting commands
\usepackage{xunicode}% unicode character macros
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[footnotesize,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{perpage} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3, WordSpace=1]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}
\newfontfamily\latin[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\greek[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}


\rightfootnoterule
\usepackage[perpage,bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 6em}

%%% ToC (table of contents)APPEARANCE
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % include subsections
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{}     % no bold!
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{فہرست ِ مضامین}

\chapterstyle{ger} 

\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{باب}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{}

\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\kern-.2em\origfootnote{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{\section*{#2  #1}}

\renewcommand*{\notesname}{نوٹس}

\renewcommand*{\notenuminnotes}[1]{\latin #1.\space}
\renewcommand*{\prenoteinnotes}{\par\noindent\hangindent 2em}

\usepackage[backend=biber,autocite=footnote,sortcites=true,   style=authortitle-icomp,block=space,notetype=endonly,firstinits=true,language=british]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\title
{کتاب\\
{وغیرہ}}
\author{خان}

\begin{document}
\setRL
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents*
\newpage
\chapter
آپ ایمان کی دوڑ میں اچھی ترقی کر رہے تھے! تو پھر کس نے آپ کو سچائی کی پیروی کرنے سے روک لیا؟ 
\footnote{گلتیوں 5:\! 7}

زہر کے پیالے کو ہونٹوں تک اُٹھا کر اُس نے بلاجھجک اور زندہ دلی سے زہر کو پی لیا۔ یہاں تک ہم جو ساتھ تھے زیادہ تر سنبھلے ہوئے تھے۔ لیکن جب دیکھا
\autocite[56--78]{Najim}
کہ وہ زہر کو پی کر تہہ تک پہنچ گیا ہے تو ہم اپنے آنسوؤں کو روک نہ سکے۔ میں بھی  اپنے آپ پر قابو نہ پا سکا بلکہ زار و قطار رونے لگا۔
\autocite[33--34]{Murray1974}

%%print endnote
\newpage
\setLR{\printpagenotes*}
%%print endnote

\newpage
\printbibliography%[heading=bibliography]%
\end{document}
```

The bibliography.bib file linked to this:

```
   @ARTICLE{Murray1974,
  author = {Robert Murray},
  title = {The Exhortation to Candidates for Ascetical Vows at Baptism in the Ancient Syrian Church},
  journal = {New Testament Studies},
  year = {1974–75},
  volume = {21},
  pages = {58–79},
  timestamp = {2013.03.13}
}

@BOOK{Najim,
  title = {Antioch and Syrian Christianity},
  author = {Najim, Michel},
  editor = {Frazer, Terry},
  subtitle = {A Chalcedonian Perspective on a Spiritual Heritage},
  timestamp = {2011.08.29},
  url = {www.stnicholasla.com/frmichel/antiochandsyriacchristianity.pdf},
  urldate = {2011-08-31}
}
```

The font Jameel Noori Nastaleeq is found here http://urdu.ca/1 (Other Operating Systems).

I should add that I have been told this is not a pure font. Some combinations of letters have been incorporated which probably bung up the works. If you replace this font with Linux Libertine O, the bibliography comes out fine (not though the Urdu). Unfortunately, this font is the only one widely used amongst Urdu readers, at least for hard copies (internet is another matter).

[image]

Comment: Can you please add an image showing the wrong part? Is the font you used free? Can you give us a link to it? BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: As to the second request (about chapter styles), I'd suggest you to post it as another question (it sounds like something that would be very useful for the community, something that would be more easily found having its own post)

Comment: I have re-edited post to reflect the the request.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both, as well as \setLTRbibitems \printbibliography. No luck. \setRL does however change the direction of the bibliography to RL. I assume that if I just write \printbibliography, bidi automatically adds  \setdefaultbibitems.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the answer was simple. I just added `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` before `\printbibliography`, and hey presto, everything worked just right.